# Is algebraic geometry related to conical intersection in potential energy surface of molecules?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, conic-sections

I post this question here because it seems that the equations describing [conical intersections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_intersection) in molecular [potential energy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy_surface) are similar to what algebraic geometry research concerns.

Potential energy surface (PES) is a function represent the molecular total energy value versus variables like bond length, bond angle, etc. Conical intersections (CI) are generated when non-adiabatic couplings happen between two adjoin states. For example, in 2D PES, a conical intersection could be a degenerate/intersect point between ground state energy surface and first excited state.

You could refer [Nonadiabatic Events and Conical Intersections](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-physchem-032210-103450) and [On the origins of intersecting potential energy surfaces](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10910-017-0746-8) for more details.

Here I give a brief explanation on how CI is emerged.

For a diatomic molecule, we have a two state electronic Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
H_{11}(R)-E & H_{12}(R) \\ 
H_{21}(R) & H_{22}(R)
\end{matrix}
\right] 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\psi_1 \\
\psi_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
=0
\end{equation}
$\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are diabatic wave functions and R represents the interatomic distance. The degenerate solutions (i.e. CI) exist if
\begin{equation}
H_{11}=H_{22}\\
H_{21}=H_{12}=0
\end{equation}
are satisfied. Obviously, it is crucial to find the correct $R$ satisfy the above conditions especially in high dimensions and more complicated Hamiltonians.

Question is, can algebraic geometry research enlighten people to solve this problem or is there something worth to read?

==========================================================

Update 1: 
Here is an example of the Hamiltonian, from [arXiv:1310.2929](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2929v1)

> The model Hamiltonian is
>   \begin{equation}
>   \label{GPLVC2D} 
>   H_{\rm 2D}= T_{\rm 2D}{\mathbf 1}_2
>   + \begin{pmatrix}
>     V_{11} & V_{12} \\
>     V_{12} & V_{22}
>   \end{pmatrix},
> \end{equation}
>   where $T_{\rm 2D}=-1/2 (\partial^2 /\partial x^2 +\partial^2 /\partial
> y^2) $ is the nuclear kinetic energy operator, $x$ and $y$ are the
>   mass-weighted coordinates, $V_{11}$ and $V_{22}$ are the diabatic
>   potentials represented by identical two-dimensional parabolas shifted
>   in space and coupled by the $V_{12}$ potential
>   \begin{align}
>   \label{eq:diab-me-11}
>   V_{11} = {} & \dfrac{\omega^2 }{2}\left[(x+x_0)^2 + y^2\right],
>   \quad  V_{12} = c y, \\
>   \label{eq:diab-me-22}
>   V_{22} = {} & \dfrac{\omega^2}{2} \left[(x-x_0)^2 + y^2\right].
> \end{align}
>   Here, $\omega$ is the frequency for both coordinates, $\pm x_0$ are
>   the minima of $V_{11}$ and $V_{22}$ potentials, and $c$ is a coupling
>   constant.  $H_{\rm 2D}$ is an electron-nuclear Hamiltonian written in
>   the so-called diabatic representation with the nuclear kinetic
>   energy operator $T_{\rm 2D}{\mathbf 1}_2$ diagonal in the electronic
>   subspace.

Comment: Could you give an example of $H_{ij}$ in some concrete siutation?

Comment: @Libli Please check the update. Here is an example how Hamiltonian looks like.

Comment: I am not at all an expert in kinetic theory, but basically in your example, the degenerate conditions can be rewritten as $V_{12} =0$ and $V_{11} = V_{22}$, right?
If this is the case, then the first condition implies $y=0$ (unless $c=0$) and the second one leads to $(x+x_0)^2 = (x-x_0)^2$, which leads to $x=0$ unless $x_0 = 0$. 
Hence for this example, degenerate solutions always exist in $(0,0)$ and if $x_0 =0$, they exist everywhere on the line $y=0$. Is it what you are looking for?